# How to creat clickable links from a list in powershell GUI

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I am writing a powershell tool for a friend to help him manage more easily some server checks.
I have a folder where I will store daily logfiles.
I want an option where the tool lists all the files and you can click on it and it opens automatically.

This is my code that reads the folder:

```
function reportlist
{
    $reportfiles = $PSScriptRoot + "\reports\"
    $reportlist = Get-ChildItem -path $reportfiles
    foreach ($report in $reportlist)
    {
        $outputBox.text += "" + $report + "`n" 
    } 
}
```

So basically I read the files using Get0Chiditem and stuff the whole thing into a textbox line by line.
And this is how it looks like in the GUI window ( I can't post images)

```
report_1_date_xx_xx_xxxx.html
report_2_date_xx_xx_xxxx.html
report_3_date_xx_xx_xxxx.html
report_4_date_xx_xx_xxxx.html
report_5_date_xx_xx_xxxx.html
```

These are the files I would like to turn into links like in HTML for example.
Is it possible to achieve it from a GUI? Sometimes when I list different windows propertys in a textbox the result appears as a link but I don't know how it is written.
Any help how to do this would be great.

Here is how I create de output box. It is a rich textbox

```
$outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.richTextBox 
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,40) 
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,500) 
$outputBox.MultiLine = $True 
$outputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical" 
$outputBox.font = "Courier new"
$Form.Controls.Add($outputBox)
```

As for the UI genertaion, every object is defined the similar way. I am not using the XAML method (I'v seen it is another way to creat powershell GUI)

This is the definition of the main form:

```
$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1050,600)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: You don't tell us what `$outputbox` is, or how it is defined.

Comment: Basic idea is to use a hyperlink control; once you mention what you're using currently for the UI generation I can explain more.

Comment: Thx for the missing info. I edited the qestion with the definition of the textbox. It is a richtextbox.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Out-GridView cmdlet`. I know it is not a hyperlink, but I think it creates the result that you want.

```
$data = 1..10

$data | ForEach-Object{Set-Content -Value $_  -Path "$_.txt"}

Get-ChildItem *.txt | Out-GridView -PassThru | %{& $_}
```

Comment: Thx for the idea. I'v been experimenting with Out-Gridview as well. I created the gridview but the links do not open on doubleclick :( ... or I am doing something wrong...

Comment: If you add the `-PassThru` param, there should be an OK button. The user can select multiple items if needed. That last little bit  | %{& $_}  just executes whatever is selected. You may need to customize it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... still did not find any solution. But I created a work around:

I created a drop down menu:

```
$DropDownBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDownBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,350) 
$DropDownBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,20) 
$DropDownBox2.DropDownHeight = 200 
$Form.Controls.Add($DropDownBox2) 
$reportfiles = $PSScriptRoot + "\reports\"
$reportlist = Get-ChildItem -path $reportfiles
foreach ($report in $reportlist)
    {
       $DropDownBox2.Items.Add($report)
    }
```

Then I created a "open file" button next to it, and onclick the button i made a small function thet opens with invoke-item the selected file:

```
function openreport
 {
  $openfile = $PSScriptRoot + "\reports\" + $DropDownBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() 
  invoke-item $openfile
}
```

Still if anyone has an idea how to make something like this from a richtextbox element I am interested.